# Android Facebook: FacebookAuthorizationException with blank message

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been testing our app on older versions of Android, specifically 2.3.3 on a Galaxy Tab and I've been unable to login. I'm using Facebook SDK 3.6.

Our app works fine on Android 4.x.x and up, but when attempting to debug on the Galaxy Tab, hitting "Login" results in an attempt to open the login dialog (The screen brings up a dialog saying "loading") but then fails without any error or crash and returns me to the previous screen. The only hint I can find on the cause is the aforementioned "FacebookAuthorizationException" error in the console, but it doesn't give any other information.

I've verified the app ID and I've rechecked the keyhash. The app ID definitely matches and the 2.3.3 gives a different keyhash to the 4.x.x version, so I added the new hash to the Facebook app settings page.

Since the console doesn't give any further info on the error, I'm at a loss as to what the issue might be. As far as I know, 2.3.3 is supported by the Facebook SDK.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Turns out older versions of Android are not fully supported by the newer Facebook SDKs. Trying on a device with 4.X.X worked fine. I never did get an answer for what the specific problem was.